# Using setter methods in constructor: bad practice?

Tags: java

I often see constructors like this

```
public class A {

   private int b;

   public A(int b) {
      setB(b);
   }

   public void setB(int b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Is this a good idea? Should I use setter methods in the constructor? Isn't it a problem if I would override either the constructor or the setter methods in a sub class?

Comment: constructor only use for initiate variable. it is not a good idea to call any method through constructor.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's probably **not** a good idea. If you don't make that class final and don't make the setName( ... ) method private or final someone else is able to extend your class and overrid the setName( ... ) method. Your constructor (in your base class) will call that method in the extending class instead of your implementation. Nobody knows what that method can do. As a rule of thumb: a constructor shouldn't call methods that can be overriden.

Comment: It's not only that: in the call of `setName()`, the subclass constructor hasn't yet been called, so final variables can be uninitialized, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should chose carefully and be aware of the downsides of each.

If the class you are defining is likely to be sub-classed then take particular care to avoid being uninitialised at a time when the subclass needs you to be complete.

This may be a useful mechanism but it is, in my opinion, unpleasant.

```
public class A {

   private int b;

   public A(int b) {
      _setB(b);
   }

   private void _setB(int b) {
      this.b = b;
   }

   public void setB(int b) {
      _setB(b);
   }
}
```

I personally would prefer that to something like this though:

```
public class A {

   private int b;

   public A(int b) {
      this.b = b;
   }

   public void setB(int b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Comment: But, if you have to check the parameter [b] before using it, you may have a redundant code !!